# Weka logistic classifier unavaliable

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I am trying to use weka to classify a dataset with logistic regression but the option logistic is unavaliable even though I use only numeric values for attributes and nominal for class (Other main classifiers are also unavaiable like NaiveBayes, J48 etc). My Arff file is :

```
@RELATION data_weka

@ATTRIBUTE class {1,0}

@ATTRIBUTE 1 NUMERIC
        .
        .
        .
@ATTRIBUTE 30 NUMERIC

@DATA

1,17.99,10.38,122.8,1001,0.1184,0.2776,0.3001,0.1471,0.2419,0.07871,1.095,0.9053,8.589,153.4,0.006399,0.04904,0.05373,0.01587,0.03003,0.006193,25.38,17.33,184.6,2019,0.1622,0.6656,0.7119,0.2654,0.4601,0.1189
             . 
             . 
             .
```

The dataset contains 562 examples.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: The data set itself might be less relevant than the *error message* (or what exactly means that it is "not available")

Comment: It loads the file and let me run classification only with some of the classifiers like ZeroR, GussianProcesses etc while logistic is greyed out.

Comment: did you set the class attribute to be your class attribute?

Answer (score 1):

In your file, the class attribute is not the last attribute.  Did you change the class attribute to be the last (class) attribute in the Preprocess Editor (right click to see that menu).

Weka always assumes the class attribute is the last attribute in the file. Your last attribute (30) is numeric, so it's not letting you run logistic regression.